# different template specialization for boost::tuple and generic structs

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm lost with templates.

I have this code in a header:

```
void push(lua_State *, bool);
void push(lua_State *, int);
void push(lua_State *, long);
void push(lua_State *, unsigned long);
void push(lua_State *, lua_Number);
void push(lua_State *, lua_CFunction);
void push(lua_State *, const char *);
void push(lua_State *, const char *, std::size_t);
void push(lua_State *, const std::string &);

template<typename T>
void push(lua_State * L, const std::vector<T> & value)
{
    lua_newtable(L);
    std::size_t size = value.size();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        lua_pushinteger(L, i + 1);
        push(L, value[i]);
        lua_settable(L, -3);
    }
}

inline void push(lua_State *, boost::tuples::null_type){}
inline void push(lua_State *, boost::tuple<>){}

template<typename HT, typename TT>
void push(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value){
    push(L, value.get_head());
    push(L, value.get_tail());
}

//Declared but not defined. *Intentional* compile-time error if trying to push a Luaproxy (undefined reference). Use Lua stack reference instead
template<typename T>
void push(lua_State* l, Luaproxy<T>& value);

template<typename T>      //most generic version
void push(lua_State* l, T& value){
    Luaproxy<T>::new_c(l, value, false);
}
```

I expect to see the `boost::tuples::cons` version of `push()` called when as second argument is passed a result of `boost::make_tuple(...)`. But I get errors at linking that show that such calls are resolved to the most generic version of `push`, that is `push(lua_State* l, T& value)`.

The final result is that I must be able to do

```
mystruct example;
push(l, boost::make_tuple(3, 4, example))
```

and this must call in turn

```
void push(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value)  //tuple contains int, int, mystruct
void push(lua_State *, int)
void push(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value)  //my tuple contains int mystruct
void push(lua_State *, int)
void push(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value)  //my tuple contains mystruct
void push(lua_State* l, T& value)
```

If I delete the most general form of my `push()` functions, the rest of the code of my application, where it calls `push()` with a typle as argument is correctly resolved to the `push(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value)` version of the function. So, for some reason the most generic version has an higher priority, and that's what I don't want.

edit:
I'm trying to follow Anycorn's suggestion, but I'm not very good at this. I'm leaving the `boost::tuples::cons` version as is, and i want to disable the generic version if the argument is derived from `boost::tuples::cons`:

```
template<typename T, typename HT, typename TT>
void push(lua_State* l, T& value, typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_base_of< boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>, T>, T>::type* =0 ){
    Luaproxy<T>::new_c(l, value, false);
}
```

and it's still considering the cons type for `push(l, boost::make_tuple(mystruct))`

> [cut]
>   /home/pisto/sorgenti/hopmodv4/src/hopmod/lua/push_function.hpp:48:6: note: template void lua::push(lua_State*, lua::Luaproxy&)
>   /home/pisto/sorgenti/hopmodv4/src/hopmod/lua/push_function.hpp:51:6: note: template void lua::push(lua_State*, const T&, typename boost::disable_if, T>, T>::type*)
>   /home/pisto/sorgenti/hopmodv4/src/hopmod/lua/push_function.hpp:56:6: note: template void lua::push(lua_State*, const boost::tuples::cons&)

Comment: seems like you are trying to do partial specialization of functions - you cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
template<> template<typename HT, typename TT>
void push< boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> >(lua_State * L, const boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT> & value){
    push(L, value.get_head());
    push(L, value.get_tail());
}
```

should be

```
template<typename HT, typename TT>
void (lua_State * L, const boost::tuple<HT, TT> & value){
    push(L, value.get_head());
    push(L, value.get_tail());
}
```

notice that make_tuple returns tuple, not cons.

*if i understood your question correctly*

update:

tuple inherits from cons.  what you must do is fail the generic template if argument isn't derivative of cons and enable it otherwise.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html

alternatively you can specialize tuple template function and cast tuple to its base, `cons`

update:

seeing what you try to do you need a way to test a tuple:
lets try this:

```
template<class T>
is_tuple : boost::mpl::false_ {};

template<class T0, class T1, ...>
struct is_tuple<tuple<T0, T1, ..> > : boost::mpl::true_ {};
```

then write function to disable/enable depending on tuple AND a function to handle `cons<H,T>`.  Tuple function must call cons function.

Comment: no, you have been misled by my example: the tuple can be of any number of arguments. I've modified the example in the question to be more clear. As far as I know, the only what to make a push() for a tuple of an arbitrary number of argument is to use this kind of "recursive metaprogramming" with boost::tuples::cons_get_head() (which returns the first argument alone) and boost::tuples::cons_get_tail() (which returns a cons with the first argument stripped out of the original cons)

Comment: I've modified the question to explain why I'm using cons too. It works without the most generic version of push().

Comment: `template<typename T, typename HT, typename TT>
void push(lua_State* l, T& value, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_base_of<boost::tuples::cons<HT, TT>, T>::value, T>::type=0){
 Luaproxy<T>::new_c(l, value, false);
}`  seems to do it, at least compiles. Hope that it's not breaking up everything in effective run. For now, I accept your answer :)

Comment: hmm, ok, it might be tricky.  you need is_tuple metafunction.  see my update in few

Comment: this is growing overly complicated. Many thanks for your efforts, but I ended up in calling the tuple version pushtuple(). I believe that this template thing in C++11 and boost is no more than a big bunch of hacks on top of hacks, just to maintain backward compatibility, with no regard to newcomers and general reading comfortability. I'm looking forward for other programming languages (D?) that were born with these metaprogramming facilities, and so are much more linear.